# Notifications review optimization

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm just curious about the review feature. For example when you finish 20 suggested edits then it tells you to come back in 5-8 hours, *but still keeps pushing notifications on available suggested edits review* though if you click on, the system replies to please come back later... and so forth.

Wouldn't it be better functionally if the system would block notifications for that period of time on suggested edits or even better: switch notification pushes for example to "Low Quality Posts" for that period of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything on the front page is subject to caching since the high number of requests take a hit on the server.

I guess it is possible to implement your request, but I have one concern: the figure can now be calculated without taking the user into account. With your request it has to. Hence it has a serious performance impact.

Besides that I think your request is quite helpful and if the server guys agree, I would like to see this implemented.

Comment: You have to take the user into account already! Just decide on a site and work a bit on a queue. Then ask another person who did not work on this queue and let him/her tell you what they see as queue size. It will differ from yours because in your counter, all items you skipped and all items you reviewed, but which did not yet reach the vote threshold are missing, while others still see them and have them counted. So this is not an argument, I think (guessing from observing the site, I don't know the internal structures, unfortunately...)

Comment: In my experience the user isn't taken into account. Can differ per site maybe?

Comment: I did this on AskUbuntu once and had different (higher) numbers for the CloseVote queue than somebody who actively has reviewed that day.